# Magnific Popup and Youtube video not able to push 'play' on iOS

Tags: ios, youtube, popup, lightbox, magnific-popup

Magnific Popup is working on desktop and other mobile devices fine, but on iOS the iframe video popup loads video but user is unable to click the play button. That is, the video loads, Youtube video appears with the large red play button but when user touches the button, nothing.

I am confused - anyone have ideas on what the issue may be? I'm using basic functionality per instructions except I have "disabledOn:0" so as to keep popup and not send user to Youtube.

```
$('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
            disableOn: 0,
            type: 'iframe',
            mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
            removalDelay: 160,
            preloader: false,

            fixedContentPos: false
        });
```